# Работа со строками(ввод строк)

Tags: c++, c

Ребят, помогите реализовать, нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил слова в программу, используя стандартный поток ввода, а чтобы программа поняла, что нужно заканчивать вводить строки, нужно воспользоваться пустой строкой(нажать два раза enter в консоли)

Comment: И что мешает вам это сделать?

Comment: Отсутствие необходимых знаний)

Comment: C: [man getline](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=getline&category=3&russian=0), C++: [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 #include<vector>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
{
vector<string> stroka;//массив для твоих строк
string s;
int i = 0;
getline(cin, s);
while (s!="")   
{
    stroka.push_back(s);
    getline(cin, s);
}
return 0;
}
```

я совсем новичок в с++,но так,по-моему,работает.

Comment: Обработку ошибок добавьте, и освобождение ресурсов не помешает.